# iOS - Google AdMob v6.12.0 - "idfa class missing, won't collect idfa"

Tags: ios, ios7, ios8, admob, idfa

I'm using Google AdMob (DFP & Mediated Interstitials) for a project in iOS 8 (target iOS 7).
And even though I've included what I think are all the necessary Frameworks for AdMob v6.12.0 (according to the AdMob site), I'm seeing the following warning message in Xcode:

> **"idfa class missing, won't collect idfa"**

According to AdMob's release notes, v6.12.0 SDK uses Apple's idfa...

> **"The SDK uses IDFA under the guidelines laid out in the iOS developer**
>   **program license agreement."** 
>   ( http://tinyurl.com/n4f3fn7 )

So... I'm stumped by this warning message in the Xcode console.

**MY QUESTION:**
Should I disregard this message?  What could I be missing here?

FYI -- Here is a list of the Frameworks I'm including in my Project:
[image]

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All you have to do is to add `libAdIdAccess.a` to your project. It is part of `GoogleAnalyticsServicesiOS_3.09` delivery.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add AdSupport.framework

That line only says that it cannot access to idfa

Comment: But what if you don't want to use AdSupport?

Comment: There is no problem in not adding AdSupport. The sdk in that case is not going to send idfa to identify every device, but it will work. What are you using Admob for exactly?

Comment: Should I check IFDA usage for the application on iTunes Connect if I add AdSupport.framework? I don't use any ads at all. Just want to use GoogleAnalytics.

Comment: Adding AdSupport doesn't help to me! GoogleAnalytics 3.08.

Comment: Idfa is usually used to identify devices in advertising campaigns.  If you only want to use googleAnalytics, forget about that warning line and do not add AdSupport framework.  If you are going to buy campaigns or to add advertising to your add, better add AdSupport and check the use of idfa when you publish the app.